# Passing a result of a cte for finding date difference between today's date & given date in sql table...not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(Availability, PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 
        [Availability]), 11) AS [Date Part]
    FROM 
        [ScrappedData_Regina]
)
-- extracts date part from a column
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Product Name],
    [SKU],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(cte AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS [Delivery Date]
FROM
    ScrappedData_Regina
-- gives date difference between todays date & given date in sql table
```

Comment: `CAST(cte.[Date Part] AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a cte as if it's a single value. A cte is a table. 
I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Product Name],
                [SKU],
                DATEDIFF(DAY, 
                      CAST(
                          SUBSTRING(
                              Availability, 
                              PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 
                                  [Availability]), 
                            11) 
                       AS DATE), 
                     CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS [Delivery Date]
FROM ScrappedData_Regina
-- gives date difference between todays date & given date in sql table
```

Or, if you insist on using a cte, you must also include the table's row identifier in it so that you can use it with join:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id, SUBSTRING(Availability, PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Availability]), 11) AS 
    FROM [ScrappedData_Regina]
)
-- extracts date part from a column
SELECT DISTINCT [Product Name],
                [SKU],
                DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST([Date Part]AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS [Delivery Date]
FROM ScrappedData_Regina t
INNER JOIN cte ON(t.Id = cte.Id)
-- gives date difference between todays date & given date in sql table
```